# Perl: Merging Hash elements

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, merge, element

I have 2 hashes.

```
my %hash1 = (
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.1.0' => 'switch_stuff1',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.3.0' => 'switch_stuff4',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.5.0' => 'switch_stuff5',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.4.0' => 'switch_stuff2',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.2.0' => 'switch_stuff3'
    );

my %hash2 = (
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.1.0' => 125858,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.3.0' => 120000,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.5.0' => 23766,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.4.0' => 115336,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.2.0' => 200
     );
```

As you can see, the key values for both hashes are the same.

What I need to do is take the **values** from `%hash1` and use them as **keys** for the `%hash2`.

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'switch_stuff1' => 125858,
          'switch_stuff4' => 120000,
          'switch_stuff5' => 23766,
          'switch_stuff2' => 115336,
          'switch_stuff3' => 200
        };
```

**Note:** The number of keys/value pairs in both hashes will always be the same.

Alternatively, the only important thing to me about `%hash1` are the values.

```
'switch_stuff1',
'switch_stuff4',
'switch_stuff5',
'switch_stuff2',
'switch_stuff3'
```

So if merging the hashes in the way I described is not possible, I can instead turn the `%hash1` into an array that contains only the values.

Can anybody please help a Perl Newbie out or at least point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ETA:**

Ah, I think I misunderstood you.. You wanted to join the two separate values into a hash. Easily done with [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
my %hash3 = map { $hash1{$_} => $hash2{$_} } keys %hash1;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my $hash1 = {
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.1.0' => 'switch_stuff1',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.3.0' => 'switch_stuff4',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.5.0' => 'switch_stuff5',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.4.0' => 'switch_stuff2',
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.2.0' => 'switch_stuff3'
};

my $hash2 = {
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.1.0' => 125858,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.3.0' => 120000,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.5.0' => 23766,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.7.4.0' => 115336,
          '1.3.6.1.2.1.6.2.0' => 200
};  

my $hash3 = {}:

foreach $key (keys %$hash1) {
   $hash3->{$hash1->{$key}} = $hash2->{$key};
}
```